# vs2015 community 'thinks' angular dependencies are installed when they are not

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2015

I used nuget package manager to install an Angular template package (HotTowel). It should install some Angular dependencies (animate, sanitize etc) but nuget is failing to download the corrensponding angularjs files into the scripts folder so when i run the project nothing works. If I try to use nuget in VS2015 it shows these as being installed. Do I really have to go and manually copy the files from angular? Why is VS2015 showing the as installed when they aren't?

```
<package id="AngularJS.Animate" version="1.2.22" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="AngularJS.Core" version="1.2.22" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="AngularJS.Route" version="1.2.22" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="AngularJS.Sanitize" version="1.2.22" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Comment: I assume the HotTowel file did get installed, just not the other dependencies it needs?

Comment: yes Hottowel files were downloaded, just those Angular files that were not?

Comment: Am I missing something or is this shoddy work by Microsoft. Surely if a file is not downloaded from a nuget source VS should let me know about that but it doesn't!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure. We don't use nuget to manage those packages, we do it manually. However, I've never seen this happen - are you sure the files aren't getting loaded anywhere in your solution? Nothing in any of the packages folders or anything else?

Comment: thx... no nowhere in the file structure. Microsofts flagship dev studio and package manager...hmmm this is shocking really....should have known it is microsoft product ;)